# Is there a tool like WinSCP for MacOS?

Tags: mac, ssh, osx-leopard, scp, winscp

I used to use WinSCP to log into my remote server. I need to login with an ssh key and move the files from and to the remote server. So far I have not find any tool with the same features for MacOS.

Any ideas? It doesn't need to be free.

Comment: If you searched already, it'd be helpful to mention the tools that didn't meet your requirements.

Comment: I thought Finder already supported this...

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/whats-a-good-graphical-sftp-utility-for-os-x

Comment: what about https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?platform=osx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) supports SFTP and [used to support SCP](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/8895) when this answer was written.

Comment: but is there an option for using ssh key? I cannot find it.

Comment: @Jakub What happens if you don't specify a password?

Comment: OK, I have figured it out. When you don't enter a password you will see an option to specify an ssh key.

Comment: ...but doesn't support sudo

Comment: Just wasted five minutes trying to get cyberduck to connect to a remote host via ssh/scp. It is seriously awful software.

Answer (score 6):

I just used **[Fugu SSH](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fugussh/)** (now on [SF](https://sf.net/)) to copy files from ssh server to a samba share, and it works great.

Fugu can also be installed using `brew install --cask fugu` from **Homebrew Cask** (not the one from Homebrew itself).

And for me the SSH connection is easier to setup in Fugu compared to cyberduck.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, though Fugo seems not supporting MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old. WinSCP 5+ works well in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) - MacOS 10.14 (Mojave) with Wine 3+.

A word to the wise on using either Cyberduck or Firefox to transfer files. If you copy a file and OS X complains about it being damaged, it is likely that the quarantine extended attribute has been set. To remove it from a file: xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine fileinquestion

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be an old thread, but for anyone still needing to use WiinSCP on a mac based OS, you can get Crossover for Mac, create a Windows Vista bottle, and then install WinSCP to the Vista bottle and it still works and runs just as great as being ran on a Windows machine. Just an FYI if someone is still looking.